# web view client does not get links

Tags: android, webview

When I setJavaScriptEnabled(true) the site stops providing links. How to fix it.

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String new_url) {
                //webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                view.loadUrl(new_url);
                if(!new_url.equals(main_url) && !new_url.equals("https://somesite.top")
                && !my_links.contains(new_url)) {
                    my_links.add(new_url);
                    my_url = new_url;
                    
                }
                Log.d("asdf", "" + new_url);
                //webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                return true;
            }

        });
```

How to solve this problem?